# Emails sent via Outlook using VBA stuck in outbox

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm attempting to send out emails with attachments via Outlook (initiated on Excel). The code runs without error but only about 6 of the 17 emails go out, the balance are stuck in outbox and go out when I open Outlook and sync the folders myself.

I've attempted using: DoEvents and Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) to no avail.

```
For counter = 2 To 18

    branchCode = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("C" & counter).Value

    BranchName = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("A" & counter).Value
    branchEmail = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("D" & counter).Value
    sheetPath = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("J2").Value
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = branchEmail
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Rate Sheet " & BranchName & " - " & Now()
        .Body = "Hi, Please find attached below your rate sheet, your uploads are ready as well."
        .Attachments.Add (sheetPath & BranchName & ".pdf")
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03"))
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing

Next counter
```

Comment: You're code works for me, no stuck emails. Might be something with your outlook.

Comment: Might be something with your Exchange server.

Comment: Why do you have `On Error Resume Next`?

Comment: Nothing to do with the server, the code to upload individual sheets works like a charm across multiple computers on two networks. The bulk send causes a issue which I suspect is due to Outlook being closed. 

With the design of this code, I tried omitting the exit lines to no avail.

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is on the code to avoid a random hang caused. This code was initially designed for one email off one sheet at a time, when rapidly firing emails, there would sometimes be an issue with the overlap of Outlook instances causing it to stop abruptly. With error handling disabled, it worked fine.

When the code was modified to run through all the sheets, I left it thinking if it ain't broke..

Comment: Is there a clear business reason to use Outlook instead of SMTP?  With SMTP you don't have to worry about Outlook and all the overhead it brings - especially the delay when loading the Outlook object.

Answer (score 1):

See adjustments to code.  Move your initialization of the Outlook application outside the loop.  You shouldn't be opening and closing these over and over and per your previous comment this is actually causing some issues, its possible that opening and closing the client successively is causing issues with the sync.

**Option 1 - Move Outlook create outside loop**

Moving the initilization outside the loop MIGHT fix your issue.  If it doesn't, try  option 2.

**Option 2 - Forcibly initiate sync of "All Accounts" sync group**

After all processing is complete we'll grab the sync groups using:

`mySyncObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects`

Then we'll kick of sync for group 1, usually "All Accounts".

`mySyncObjects(1).Start`

If this isn't "All Accounts" you'll need to loop through mySyncObjects to find it, using the property `.Name`

Adjusted code(note if to check for sending emails):

```
'determine if you need to send emails
If needToSendEmails = 1 Then

Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

For counter = 2 To 18



    branchCode = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("C" & counter).Value

    BranchName = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("A" & counter).Value
    branchEmail = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("D" & counter).Value
    sheetPath = Workbooks("Upload.xlsm").Worksheets("Branch List").Range("J2").Value

    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = branchEmail
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Rate Sheet " & BranchName & " - " & Now()
        .Body = "Hi, Please find attached below your rate sheet, your uploads are ready as well."
        .Attachments.Add (sheetPath & BranchName & ".pdf")
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    ''This shouldn't be neccessary. I utilizie similar code to send 100+ emails quickly.  It takes a second for outlook to update but all should appear inside the app when processing complete.
    ''Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:03")) 
    Set OutMail = Nothing


Next counter
''GET ALL SYNC GROUPS
Set mySyncObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects

''KICK OFF SYNC FOR ITEM 1 IN SYNC GROUPS, USUALLY ALL ACCOUNTS - MAY NEED TO LOOP THROUGH ALL SYNC GROUPS TO FIND "ALL ACCOUNTS"
mySyncObjects(1).Start

Set OutApp = Nothing

End If
```

Comment: I added this just after the loop as it would be ideal, however, I get an error of "invalid procedure call or argument" at the line mySyncObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects

Comment: See edit to answer, I'm a bit concerned that re-initializing the outlook app might be the problem.  I would suggest moving the Outlook initialization outside the loop first, testing that and if that fails, putting in the indicated lines of code BEFORE you de-allocate the OutApp object.

Comment: Attempted initialising Outlook outside the loop. `mySyncObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects` Results in the same error. I amended it to `Set mySyncObjects = OutApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").SyncObjects` which allows the code to run. However, still doesn't work out, looks almost as if Outlook is being closed before it can complete. DoEvents does nothing to help. 

Moving Outlook create/end outside the loop and adding `Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:05"))` appears to help the issue. However, if the time is less than it take Outlook to send, the unsent emails get blocked.

Comment: So there's basically 3 ways to account for this.  1. Wait-probably not ideal. 2.Try and capture the sync completion event from outlook.  Best option-not sure how to handle capturing events from other applications in VBA. 3.Loop through folder-object for outbox until no items remain. -Potentially feasible, also not ideal as it'll likely eat up a huge amount of system resources in the meantime.